# How do I pass master id to detail foreign key?

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core-mvc, master-detail

I have a master-detail edit that doesn't work as it should.

`TaBarHeader` - master and `TaBarBody` - detail, have one-to-many relationship:

```
public partial class TaBarHeader
   {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ListaOtf { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TaBarBody> TaBarBodies { get; set; }
        public IEnumerable<TaBarTelegrama> TaBarTelegramas { get; set; }
  }

public partial class TaBarBody
   {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Codstatie1 { get; set; }
        public int BarHeaderId { get; set; }
        [ForeignKey("BarHeaderId")]
        public TaBarHeader BarHeaderFk { get; set; }
   }
```

`HeaderTelegrama/Details.cshtml`:

```
@model TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.HeaderTelegramaViewModel
        <dt class="col-sm-2">
          @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaBarHeader.ListaOtf)
        </dt>
        <dd class="col-sm-10">
          @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.TaBarHeader.ListaOtf)
        </dd>
(...)
          <th>
              @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.TaBarBody.Codstatie1)
          </th>

        @foreach (var item in Model.TaBarHeader.TaBarBodies)
        {
           <tr>
              <td>
                  @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Codstatie1)
              </td>

<a asp-controller="BodyTelegrama" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id">Edit</a>
```

`BodyTelegrama/Edit.cshtml`:

```
@model TraficAlert.Models.ViewModels.BodyTelegramaViewModel
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Edit";
}

<h1>Edit</h1>

<h4>TaBarBody</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Edit">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
<div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Codstatie1" class="control-label">Cod Statie 1</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Codstatie1" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Codstatie1" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Codstatie2" class="control-label">Cod Statie 2</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Codstatie2" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Codstatie2" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtIniP" class="control-label">Data Ini P</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtIniP" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtIniP" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtFinP" class="control-label">Data Fin P</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtFinP" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtFinP" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtIniR" class="control-label">Data Ini R</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtIniR" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtFinP" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtFinR" class="control-label">Data Fin R</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtFinR" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.DtFinR" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.KmIni" class="control-label">Km Ini</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.KmIni" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.KmIni" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.KmFin" class="control-label">Km Fin</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.KmFin" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.KmFin" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.LiniaFir" class="control-label">Linia Fir</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.LiniaFir" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.LiniaFir" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.NomImpactId" class="control-label">Impact</label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.NomImpactId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.NomImpactId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.NomAnulatId" class="control-label">Anulat</label>
                <select asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.NomAnulatId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.NomAnulatId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.MotivAnulare" class="control-label">Motiv Anulare</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.MotivAnulare" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.MotivAnulare" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Ruta" class="control-label">Ruta</label>
                <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Ruta" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Ruta" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.TelegramaId" value="Save" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>
```

`BodyTelegramaController`:

```
// GET
    public IActionResult Edit(int id, int HeaderTelegramaId)
    {
        BodyTelegramaViewModel bodyTelegramaViewModel = new BodyTelegramaViewModel();
        bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody = new TaBarBody();
        bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.BarHeaderFk = new TaBarHeader();
        bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody = _unitofwork.BarBody.DetailsBarB(id);
        bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.BarHeaderFk = _unitofwork.BarHeader.DetailsBarHB(id);

        ViewData["TelegramaId"] = HeaderTelegramaId;

        if (bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        ViewData["NomImpactId"] = new SelectList(_unitofwork.NomImpact.GetAll(), "Id", "Nume");
        ViewData["NomAnulatId"] = new SelectList(_unitofwork.NomAnulat.GetAll(), "Id", "Nume");

        return View(bodyTelegramaViewModel);
    }


// POST
    public IActionResult Edit(int id, BodyTelegramaViewModel bodyTelegramaViewModel)
    {
        if (id != bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.Id)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            try
            {
                bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.BarHeaderId = id;
                _unitofwork.BarBody.Update(bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody);
                _unitofwork.Save();
    }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!TaBarBodyExists(bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.Id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
}
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        return View(bodyTelegramaViewModel);
    }
```

Everytime I edit a record, my foreign key - BarHeaderId - change its value to 0.

I have tried `bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.BarHeaderId = bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarHeader.Id;` but I get the error 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

How can I get the `TaBarHeader.Id` value and put it in `TaBarBody.BarHeaderId`?

**Update**:

ViewModels:

```
public class HeaderTelegramaViewModel
{
    public TaBarHeader TaBarHeader { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaBarHeader> taBarHeader { get; set; }
    public TaBarBody TaBarBody { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaBarBody> taBarBody { get; set; }
}

public class BodyTelegramaViewModel
{
    public TaBarBody TaBarBody { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<TaBarBody> taBarBody { get; set; }
}
```

HeaderTelegramaController:

```
    public IActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        HeaderTelegramaViewModel headerTelegramaViewModel = new HeaderTelegramaViewModel();
        headerTelegramaViewModel.TaBarHeader = _unitofwork.BarHeaderRepository.DetailsBarHB(id);

        if (headerTelegramaViewModel == null)
        {
            return NotFound();
        }
        return View(headerTelegramaViewModel);
    }
```

BodyTelegramaController:

```
// GET
public IActionResult Edit(int id)
{
    BodyTelegramaViewModel bodyTelegramaViewModel = new BodyTelegramaViewModel();
    bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody = new TaBarBody();
    bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.BarHeaderFk = new TaBarHeader();
    bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody = _unitofwork.BarBodyRepository.DetailsBarB(id);
    bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.BarHeaderFk = _unitofwork.BarHeaderRepository.DetailsBarHB(id);
    return View(bodyTelegramaViewModel);
}
```

These are the methods `DetailsBarB()` and `DetailsBarHB()`:

```
    public TaBarBody DetailsBarB(int id)
    {
        return _db.TaBarBodies
            .Include(t => t.BarHeaderFk)
            .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
    }

    public TaBarHeader DetailsBarHB(int id)
    {
        return _db.TaBarHeaders
        .Include(x => x.TaBarBodies).ThenInclude(x => x.BarHeaderFk.CategoriaFk)
        .FirstOrDefault(m => m.Id == id);
    }
```

Comment: Please share your `ViewModel` and your `HeaderTelegrama/Details` action.

Comment: I have added the requested information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do following changes to get the `TaBarHeader` id.

In your `Details View`,change it to:

```
 <a asp-controller="BodyTelegrama" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="@item.Id" asp-route-HeaderTelegramaId="@Model.TaBarHeader.Id">Edit</a>
```

In your `Edit` action,change it to:

```
public IActionResult Edit(int id,int HeaderTelegramaId)
{
    BodyTelegramaViewModel bodyTelegramaViewModel = new BodyTelegramaViewModel();
    bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody = new TaBarBody();
    bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.BarHeaderFk = new TaBarHeader();
    bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody = _unitofwork.BarBodyRepository.DetailsBarB(id);
    bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.BarHeaderFk = _unitofwork.BarHeaderRepository.DetailsBarHB(id);

    ViewData["TelegramaId"] = HeaderTelegramaId;

    return View(bodyTelegramaViewModel);
}
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Edit(int id, BodyTelegramaViewModel bodyTelegramaViewModel)
{
 bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.BarHeaderId = id;
 _unitofwork.BarBodyRepository.Update(bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody);
 _unitofwork.Save();
 return View(bodyTelegramaViewModel);
}
```

Then in your `Edit View`,change it to:

```
<form asp-action="Edit">
<div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>

<div class="form-group">
    <input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Id" />
    <label asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Codstatie1" class="control-label">Cod Statie 1</label>
    <input asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Codstatie1" class="form-control" />
    <span asp-validation-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Codstatie1" class="text-danger"></span>
</div>
<div>
    <input type="submit" asp-route-id="@ViewBag.TelegramaId" value="Save"/>
</div>
</form>
```

Then in your `Edit` post action,the `id` will be the `TaBarHeader.Id`.

Test Result:

[image]

Comment: I have tried the above code and added `bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.BarHeaderId = id;` in Edit post action, but after I edit a record I.e. with Id 49 and HeaderTelegramaId=6 I get Error 404 No webpage was found for the web address: https://localhost:44313/BodyTelegrama/Edit/6.

Comment: I did the changes in my code and removed `<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Id" />` from Edit View, but I get the same error 404.

Comment: Please share your whole `BodyTelegrama/Edit.cshtml` code.

Comment: Or you can try to change to `return RedirectToAction("Index", "HeaderTelegrama");` in your post edit action.

Comment: The first thing you need to make sure is that your form is successfully submitted to your post edit action and the id is successfully obtained. You can breakpoint observation

Comment: I have shared the whole `BodyTelegrama/Edit.cshtml`. Also, I have seen your gif, so I put a breakpoint and noticed that my Id is ok but `bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.BarHeaderId` is 0. Furthermore, I have attached the whole Edit get and post actions from BodyTelegramaController.

Comment: Your edit post action's id is `BarHeaderId`,you don't need to get it in the  bodyTelegramaViewModel.

Comment: You need add `[HttpPost]` above your post action.

Comment: I have added `return RedirectToAction("Index", "HeaderTelegrama");` but I get the same error.  `[HttpPost]` and `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]` were present above my method.

Comment: Sorry, I was referring to `bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.Id` is 0 - https://imgur.com/qGPVfkt

Comment: If you want to get it,you can add `<input type="hidden" asp-for="@Model.TaBarBody.Id" />` in your view.

Comment: Thank you, @Yinqiu , for your valuable help. I have corrected the issue by removing this: `if (id != bodyTelegramaViewModel.TaBarBody.Id) { return NotFound(); }` from the Edit post and now it's working.